# converting excel 2003 to 2007 or recent version with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have an xls excel file (excel 97-2003 workbook) in which there is vba code.
I want to convert it to 2007 or newer version of excel with this vba code enabled.
I have tried:

1. save as macro-enabled.xlsm file
2. changed the settings of macros from [this](http://www.ehow.com/how_6056661_convert-2003-macros-excel-2007.html) blog.
   it changed the document in .xlsm but on values of cell (on which macro is running) it shows #NAME instead of values.
   orignal file screen shot:
   [image]

converted:
[image]
I am stuck here.

the code of macros:

1.moveAcross.bas

```
    Attribute VB_Name = "MoveAcross"
Sub GoToValues()
Attribute GoToValues.VB_Description = "Macro recorded 23-01-2001 by Murad Assaggaf"
Attribute GoToValues.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = " \n14"
'
' GoToValues Macro
' Macro recorded 23-01-2001 by Murad Assaggaf
'

'
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=13
    ActiveWindow.LargeScroll Down:=-2
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-3
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
    Range("X6").Select
End Sub
Sub ReturnToProfileArea()
Attribute ReturnToProfileArea.VB_Description = "Macro recorded 23-01-2001 by Murad Assaggaf"
Attribute ReturnToProfileArea.VB_ProcData.VB_Invoke_Func = " \n14"
'
' ReturnToProfileArea Macro
' Macro recorded 23-01-2001 by Murad Assaggaf
'

'
    Range("G5").Select
End Sub
```

2.Demand.bas

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Demand"
Function Demand(m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, EndInv, ST, Fraction)
    Static months(7) As Variant

    months(0) = m0
    months(1) = m1
    months(2) = m2
    months(3) = m3
    months(4) = m4
    months(5) = m5
    months(6) = m6

    Dim summy
    summy = 0

    If Fraction > 0 Then
        summy = months(ST + 1) * Fraction
    End If

    For n = 0 To ST
        summy = summy + months(n)
    Next n

    Demand = summy - EndInv

    If Demand < 0 Then
        Demand = 0
    End If
    End Function
```

3.Coverage.bas

```
Attribute VB_Name = "Coverage"
Function Coverage(m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, EndInv, ST, Fraction)

    Static months(7) As Variant

    months(0) = m0
    months(1) = m1
    months(2) = m2
    months(3) = m3
    months(4) = m4
    months(5) = m5
    months(6) = m6

    Dim summy
    summy = 0

    If Fraction > 0 Then
        summy = months(ST) * Fraction
    End If

    For n = 0 To (ST - 1)
        summy = summy + months(n)
    Next n

    Coverage = EndInv / (summy / (ST + Fraction))

End Function
```

Edited screenshot of VBA:
[image]

Comment: Help us to hep you, **post the code that fails.**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent please check, i uploaded the code.

Comment: Which one fails, where? Do they run properly but just return the `#Name` error? Are you putting one of your functions in that cell? Which one?

Comment: @AxelRichter its =Demand.Demand and so on. but i tried while changing names but unfortunately not working in my case.

Comment: @BruceWayne macro runs without any error but on values it shows #NAME.

Comment: @AxelRichter i made functions public and and changed formula to Demand(...) but couldn't get any result

Comment: @AxelRichter screenshot link = http://prntscr.com/dog1o0

Comment: @AxelRichter you dont need to download its just a link of image.
p.s. i have uploaded image in question as well, please check

Comment: According to your screenshot - modules are named exactly like the functions in it - `=coverage.coverage(...)` should work. Of course if parameters refers to cells which results in `#NAME`, then this error will go through. So all formulas need to be in this form `=[ModuleName].[FunctionName](...)` if modules are named exactly like the functions in it. If all not works then I suspect macros are not enabled at all.

Comment: You never told us what version of Excel you're running the conversion on. If it is 2003 it won't work.

Comment: Are the #NAME? cells a formula in the workbook. or a result of the macro?

Comment: @Peter I am using 2007 and 2016 on another PC, it's not working on both.also tried on 2013.

Comment: @gemmo these are results of Macro.

Comment: Can you check in VB Editor --> Tools --> References if there are any libraries selected starting from [MISSING] or something similar? If yes, unselect it and then try.

Comment: @Rufus thanks man, it helps a lot, can you please post in anwser so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check in VB Editor --> Tools --> References if there are any libraries selected starting from MISSING:
[image]

If yes, then unselect it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the code in "ThisWorkbook" if you want to call it in a worksheet.